# Solving a large sparse linear system using Cholesky Method in Eigen

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

I am actually trying to solve a large sparse linear system using Cholesky Method in Eigen.
I have downloaded a sparse matrix (cfd1) from [this site](https://sparse.tamu.edu/Rothberg/cfd1). I tried to solve the linear system Ax = b defined as following: A is the matrix cfd1, b = A * xe where xe is a vector of ones having the same size of matrix' number of rows. In conclusion, using the Matlab notation I would like to solve: `x = A\b`. Here the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/SparseExtra>
#include<Eigen/SparseCholesky>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;
int main()
{

   SparseMatrix<double> mat;
   VectorXd x;
   loadMarket(mat, "Path of downloaded matrix");

   cout << "Number of Rows:\n" << mat.rows() << endl;

   ArrayXd xe = ArrayXd::Constant(mat.rows(), 1);
   cout << xe << endl;
   SparseVector<double> b = mat*xe;

   SimplicialLLT<SparseMatrix<double> > solver;
   x = solver.compute(mat).solve(b);
   cout << x << endl;



}
```

The problem is that when I compile I obtain the current error:

> ```
> error: invalid operands to binary expression
>       ('SparseMatrix<double>' and 'Eigen::ArrayXd' (aka 'Array<double, Dynamic,
>       1>'))
>    SparseVector<double> b = mat*xe;
>                             ~~~^~~
> /Users/anto/Desktop/example/eigen-eigen-323c052e1731/Eigen/src/SparseCore/../plugins/CommonCwiseBinaryOps.h:50:29:
> note: 
>       candidate function template not viable: no known conversion from
>       'Eigen::ArrayXd' (aka 'Array<double, Dynamic, 1>') to 'const
>       Eigen::SparseMatrixBase<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, 0, int>
>       >::StorageBaseType' (aka 'const
>       Eigen::SparseMatrixBase<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, 0, int> >') for 2nd
>       argument
> ```

Can anyone help me to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

- You can't mix `Array` and `Matrix` in product expressions, i.e., replace `ArrayXd` by `VectorXd`.
- The product of a sparse matrix by a dense vector is generally dense, therefore you need to assign the product to a dense `VectorXd` instead of a `SparseVector`

The following compiles

```
SparseMatrix<double> mat;
loadMarket(mat, "Path of downloaded matrix");

cout << "Number of Rows:\n" << mat.rows() << endl;

VectorXd xe = VectorXd::Constant(mat.rows(), 1);
cout << xe << endl;
VectorXd b = mat*xe;

SimplicialLLT<SparseMatrix<double> > solver;
VectorXd x = solver.compute(mat).solve(b);
cout << x << endl;
```